# Задача на двумерное динамическое программирование

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Начала изучать динамическое программирование. Есть задача: поле NxM, шар может двигаться вверх, вниз, влево и вправо. Начинает свой путь из клетки [0][0], а заканчивает в [N-1][M-1]. На вход принимается двумерный массив который заполнен неотрицательными числами. Необходимо добраться из начально клетки до конечной и собрать минимальную сумму чисел.
Алгоритм сам вроде поняла, но проблема возникает в том, что в массиве dp, который я использую для записи посчитанных соседних сумм и выбора из них минимальной, некоторые  значения являются нулями. Так выходит из-за того что по умолчанию массив заполнен нулями, а по моему циклу данное значение еще не заполнено. Поэтому выходит неверный результат. Вопрос в том, как это исправить? Или надо полностью менять алгоритм?
В примерах, что читала обычно объект двигался только вправо и вниз и такой проблемы из-за этого и не возникало. Я делала на Java, но могу почитать объяснения и на других языках. Привела часть кода:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    dp[0][0] = 0;
                } else if (i == 0) {
                    if (j == M-1) {
                        dp[i][j] = Math.min(dp[i][j-1], dp[i+1][j]) + map[i][j];
                    } else {
                        dp[i][j] = minOf3(dp[i][j-1], dp[i+1][j], dp[i][j+1]) + map[i][j];
                    }
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    if (i == N-1) {
                        dp[i][j] = Math.min(dp[i][j+1], dp[i-1][j]) + map[i][j];
                    } else {
                        dp[i][j] = minOf3(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j+1], dp[i+1][j]) + map[i][j];
                    }
```

Comment: Если шарику нельза залезать на ```клетку = 0``` то можно зделать условие что шарик должен идти на ```клетку > 0```

Comment: Заполните массив dp заведомо большим числом (MAXINT), тогда выбор минимума будет работать, как надо. Вот только обеспечит ли данный подход нахождение оптимального решения для случая, например, когда путь спускается к нижнему правому углу, потом возвращается к верхнему левому (через две клетки от первой части пути), потом уже идёт снова на выход? [Картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaliG.png)

Comment: Я заполнила массив большим числом, пока для всех тестовых случаев программа работает правильно и все считает хорошо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заполните массив `dp` заведомо большим числом (`MAXINT`), тогда выбор минимума будет работать, как надо.